# implementing callback between Python and C

Tags: python, c, callback, swig

I have wrapped some C code using SWIG to use it as a python library.

Within this framework, some python code I have written calls a C function, which returns a string. However, for creating the string, the C function requires a ranking, the generation of which I have implemented in Python. How would I go about implementing this using callbacks?

I see this as the following multistep process.

1) Python instantiates a C object:
      import test_Objects #test_Objects is the C file that has been wrapped
      C = test_objects.my_class()

2) Call the relevant method on the my_class object, which return a string:
      txt_1 = "string1"
      txt_2 - "string2"
      result = C.sorted_string(txt_1, txt_2)

2.1) I want sorted_string to call the following python function, which returns a sorted list.

```
   def sorted_string([my_list]):
       .....
       .....
       return your_list
```

2.2) Sorted_string would make use of the list to generate the result.

How would I implement step 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

The [`PyObject_Call*()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Call) functions can be used to call a Python function or method from C.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on how to implement this through swig?

Comment: Nope. But once you get a function object, it's all over.

Answer (score 0):

It is not specific to your question, but here is an example that I asked: [swig-passing-argument-to-python-callback-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843064/swig-passing-argument-to-python-callback-function)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: joon: I saw your post earlier and thats what prompted me to ask my question. I see callback.c and callback.i. Can you give me a pointer to your .py file (the one you wrote, not the one that is generated by SWIG) that contains the function that callback.c invokes? Also, I noticed that you don't have a callback.h file? Doesn't SWIG require one?